Reconsructing original array from MultiArrayLayout message
I'm using the MultiArrayLayout message for the 2D grid map, but i don't know how to reconstruct the 2D array, can anyone give me example for it.

Last year I used this gist by jarvisschultz which showed how to pack and unpack a 2D array using Float32MultiArray message type. In theory this should work for the problem you are describing.
